# How to transform input parameters in POST azure api management system to XML and make it as request body?

Tags: xml, azure, transformation, azure-api-management

I have a credentials field in xml file which i am providing as input request body for POST call in azure api management system. I wanted to add those credentials as parameters and then those credentials have to be added in the xml file(transformation) before making an api call. How can i able to do that?

Comment: Baically those credentials each time have to be  added to the credentials field  in the xml when we procvide them as a input parameters in azure api management system POST call.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear as what kind of parameters you want to add those credentials.  It in general, you can do something like below:

```
<set-variable name="body" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<XElement>(true))"/>
<set-query-parameter name="creds">
    <value>@(((XElement)context.Variables["body"]).Element("XXX").Value)</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```